# 'username: req.body.username' username in last of line is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I am creating login-register system in my project, actually I made it in many of my previous projects but this time I am getting an error, for which I've seen many posts related to this but none of them worked for me.

I got some issues on "verifySignUp.js" that

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

on last 'undefined' of line 'username: req.body.username'

and This is my postman data push

```
   {
      "username":"deayhrovv",
      "email":"deayhrovv@gmail.com",
      "password":"123456",
      "roles":["user","moderater"]
   }
```

this is my server.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");

var dbConfig = require("./app/config/db.config");
var db = require("./app/models");
var Role = db.role;
var app = express();

// routes
require('./app/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes')(app);

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};

db.mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.HOST}:${dbConfig.PORT}/${dbConfig.DB}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");
    initial();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Connection error", err);
    process.exit();
});

function initial() {
    Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
      if (!err && count === 0) {
        new Role({
          name: "user"
        }).save(err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          }
  
          console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
        });
  
        new Role({
          name: "moderator"
        }).save(err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          }
  
          console.log("added 'moderator' to roles collection");
        });
  
        new Role({
          name: "admin"
        }).save(err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          }
  
          console.log("added 'admin' to roles collection");
        });
      }
    });
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Canteen Food Order APIs application ."});
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on url ${corsOptions.origin}.`);
});
```

This is my middlewares

```js
const { verifySignUp } = require("../middlewares");
const controller = require("../controllers/auth.controller");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.post(
    "/api/auth/signup",
    [
      verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
      verifySignUp.checkRolesExisted
    ],
    controller.signup
  );

  app.post("/api/auth/signin", controller.signin);
};
```

This is my verifySignUp.js

```js
const db = require("../models");
const ROLES = db.ROLES;
const User = db.user;

checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne()

  // Username
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    if (user) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "Failed! Username is already in use!" });
      return;
    }

    // Email
    User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
    }).exec((err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
      }

      if (user) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Failed! Email is already in use!" });
        return;
      }

      next();
    });
  });
};

checkRolesExisted = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.roles) {
    for (let i = 0; i < req.body.roles.length; i++) {
      if (!ROLES.includes(req.body.roles[i])) {
        res.status(400).send({
          message: `Failed! Role ${req.body.roles[i]} does not exist!`
        });
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  next();
};

const verifySignUp = {
  checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
  checkRolesExisted
};

module.exports = verifySignUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase of `GET` request, you need to access the parameters using `req.query` instead of `req.body`. So, modify the `simple route` to following

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Username = req.query.username
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Canteen Food Order APIs application ." + Username });
});
```

Comment: No. I mean "username = req.body.username" in "verifySignUp.js" but i already change "body" to "query" and it still not work